# Грамматическая основа

Tags: синтаксис

Добрый день! Помогите верно найти грамматич.основу предложения:" Их значительно больше,чем растений."

Answer (score 5):

Людмила права, грамматическая основа - слово "больше". Я помню этот тест, но все равно нашла его на сайте и в книге Цыбулько (30 тестов для подготовки к ЕГЭ). У меня эта книга за 2013 год, но эти тесты перепечатывают уже не один год. Так вот в  книге все правильно, это верный ответ. А на сайте один из вариантов почему-то заменили, получилось 2 верных ответа, программа показывает только один. Так что Вы и Людмила правы.  Ошибка допущена при составлении теста.

Answer (score 2):

Больше - сост. именное сказуемое, выраженное сравнит. степенью.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я тоже так решила, но автор теста дает это, как неверный ответ... 
Тест взят на Решу ЕГЭ

Comment: Это в школьной грамматике. Если вы в вузе,смотрите в лекции. К генитивным предложениям у учёных разный подход. Кто- то генитив(родительный падеж) включает в сказуемое, кто-то считает подлежащим.

Comment: т.е.,каков верный ответ,если ребенок учится в 11 классе?

Comment: Значит, имелось в виду "больше,чем растений"."Здесь тоже один из трудных случаев. Задание некорректно,на ЕГЭ трудных случаев не должно быть.Здесь "больше чем" - оборот, но при наличии запятой его чаще считают обстоятельством.Опять-таки разные взгляды на вопрос. Последнее время перебарывает петербургская лингвистическая школа, они считают сказуемым всё вместе с оборотом.